# Can a 15 year old who was refused a visa still travel to the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, international-travel, visa-refusals

My two cousins in Peru both applied two weeks ago for a UK visa. The older cousin got his visa, but the younger one's was rejected. He is 15 years old and did not include authorization from parents, which he didn't know that he needed.

Is it still possible for the 15 year old to travel in four days with his brother if he takes with him the authorization from their parents? He has a Peruvian passport, and wants to go to the UK for 5 days for tourism.

They have booked tickets already and the older brother has his UK visa.

Comment: I checked Peruvian nationality,  tourism on [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y). It came back as standard visa needed, with no exception for age.

Comment: Your younger cousin needs a visa, I am sorry to say.

Answer (score 8):

[GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18) guidance for someone under 18 applying for a Standard Visitor visa is:

> ### If you're under 18
>
> You can apply for a standard visitor visa if you’re under 18 and:
>
> - you’ve made suitable arrangements for your travel and stay in the UK
> - you have consent from your parent or guardian to travel to the UK
> - you’re able to pay for your return or onward journey
> - you have enough money to support yourself without working or getting help from
>     public funds, or you have family and friends that can support you
>
> #### Travelling alone
>
> You can travel to the UK without an adult (someone over the age of
>   18).
>
> Your parent or guardian will need to provide their:
>
> - written consent for you to travel to the UK
> - full contact details
>
> They’ll also need to provide proof that you have somewhere suitable to
>   live during your stay in the UK, including:
>
> - the name and date of birth of the person that you will be staying with
> - an address where you will be living
> - details of your relationship to the person who’ll be looking after you
> - consent in writing so they can look after you during your stay in the UK
>
> #### Travelling with an adult
>
> When travelling to the UK with an adult (someone over the age of 18),
>   you’ll need to identify them in your visa application.
>
> If the person you’re travelling with isn’t your parent, you’ll need to
>   provide specific information about them in your application.
>
> Their name will appear on your visa, and you’ll be refused entry to
>   the UK if you arrive in the UK without them.
>
> You can identify up to 2 adults in your visa application, and your
>   visa will only be valid if you travel with at least one of them.
>
> The adult can apply for a visa at the same time, but you must each
>   complete separate applications.